# Can't understand this part of C# code

Tags: c#, machine-learning

This part of code has been taken from [this tutorial](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/Infer.NET%20Learners%20-%20Bayes%20Point%20Machine%20classifiers%20-%20Introduction.aspx) regarding using Learners in Infer.NET library. I'm planning to use it for machine learning but unfortunately i can't get this code fragment. Please help me out.

```
/// <summary>
/// A mapping for the Bayes Point Machine classifier tutorial.
/// </summary>
public class ClassifierMapping 
    : IClassifierMapping<IList<Vector>, int, IList<string>, string, Vector>
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GetInstances(IList<Vector> featureVectors)
    {
        for (int instance = 0; instance < featureVectors.Count; instance++)
        {
            yield return instance;
        }
    }

    public Vector GetFeatures(int instance, IList<Vector> featureVectors)
    {
        return featureVectors[instance];
    }

    public string GetLabel(
        int instance, IList<Vector> featureVectors, IList<string> labels)
    {
        return labels[instance];
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetClassLabels(
        IList<Vector> featureVectors = null, IList<string> labels = null)
    {
        return new[] { "Female", "Male" };
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only remotely complicated bit is the `yield return`:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetInstances(IList<Vector> featureVectors)
{
    for (int instance = 0; instance < featureVectors.Count; instance++)
    {
        yield return instance;
    }
}
```

Which could be replaced with:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetInstances(IList<Vector> featureVectors)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    for (int instance = 0; instance < featureVectors.Count; instance++)
    {
       result.Add(instance);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is creating a Mapping class which is implementing `IClassifierMapping` interface.

```
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/Infer.NET%20Learners%20-%20Bayes%20Point%20Machine%20classifiers%20-%20API%20-%20Mappings%20-%20Standard%20Data%20Format%20Mapping.aspx
```

There are other mapping interfaces as well as can be seen here.

```
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/Infer.NET%20Learners%20-%20Bayes%20Point%20Machine%20classifiers%20-%20API%20-%20Mappings.aspx
```

With this mapping class, you can now create a Bayes Point Machine classifier.

Regarding the complexity of the code, you can look at westons answer.